# Complex List Field - Gravity Forms

Tags: css, forms, list, plugin-gravity-forms

So I am using this Complex List instruction from [LINK](https://gravitywp.com/complex-list-field-gravity-forms/) and it works, but it is changing all my lists.  I've tried a few things but am missing something...

```
.gform_wrapper ul.gform_fields.form_sublabel_above table.gfield_list td::before, 
.gform_wrapper ul.gform_fields.form_sublabel_below table.gfield_list td::after {
  content: attr(data-label);
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: .5pt;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  display: block;
  clear: both;
```

I've tried adding `#field_35_53` to the front of it so it would target just that field, but to no avail.  Anyone got any bright ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind... got it and feel stupid.  This did the trick:

```
#field_35_53 td::after {
  content: attr(data-label);
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: .5pt;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```